# How to Use the Same handleChange Event on Different Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a function which can disabled textfield when checkbox is checked.

The function is doing what I wanted, but when I trying to make multiple fields with the same function, the components are just bind together.

I've tried to handle them with **event.target** but I think I messed it up so I deleted the lines.

What should I do so they can separated into two components working individually?

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [required, setRequired] = React.useState(true);
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setRequired(!required);
    setChecked(!checked);
    setDisabled(!disabled);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={required}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text1"
          disabled={disabled}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb1"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleChange}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={required}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text1"
          disabled={disabled}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb1"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleChange}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's my sandbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3zvmp5?file=demo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself.

```
export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [required, setRequired] = React.useState({ setA: true, setB: true });
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState({ setA: false, setB: false });
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState({ setA: false, setB: false });

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={required.setA}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text1"
          disabled={disabled.setA}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb1"
          checked={checked.setA}
          onChange={() => {
            setRequired({ ...required, setA: !required.setA });
            setChecked({ ...checked, setA: !checked.setA });
            setDisabled({ ...disabled, setA: !disabled.setA });
          }}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={required.setB}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text2"
          disabled={disabled.setB}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb2"
          checked={checked.setB}
          onChange={() => {
            setRequired({ ...required, setB: !required.setB });
            setChecked({ ...checked, setB: !checked.setB });
            setDisabled({ ...disabled, setB: !disabled.setB });
          }}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x16kv6?file=demo.tsx).

However, I decided to separate the hooks.

It's not a large component so I decided to make hooks function individually to avoid any issue might happen in the same hook.

```
export default function Checkboxes() {
  const [requiredA, setRequiredA] = React.useState(true);
  const [checkedA, setCheckedA] = React.useState(false);
  const [disabledA, setDisabledA] = React.useState(false);    

  const [requiredB, setRequiredB] = React.useState(true);
  const [checkedB, setCheckedB] = React.useState(false);
  const [disabledB, setDisabledB] = React.useState(false);
  
  const handleChangeA = () => {
    setRequiredA(!requiredA);
    setCheckedA(!checkedA);
    setDisabledA(!disabledA);
  };
      
  const handleChangeB = () => {
    setRequiredB(!requiredB);
    setCheckedB(!checkedB);
    setDisabledB(!disabledB);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={requiredA}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text1"
          disabled={disabledA}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb1"
          checked={checkedA}
          onChange={handleChangeA}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
      <form>
        <TextField
          required={requiredB}
          autoComplete="off"
          id="standard-required"
          label="text2"
          disabled={disabledB}
        />

        <Checkbox
          label="cb2"
          checked={checkedB}
          onChange={handleChangeB}
          color="primary"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

sandbox [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wfjhjm?file=demo.tsx).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use state for this purpose. This can be done with manipulating the DOM easily. I have edited your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-git4be?file=demo.tsx) in the above link. Just pass the id of the input element to the function and disable it using normal javascript.